# Debugging code with STL map

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing a code for Breadth First Search algorithm. In the problem context, a node is defined as an array of 8 integers that can have both positive and negative numbers. Positive numbers are said to be male and negatives are said to be female. Two digits can dance, if one of them are male and another one is female, and the sum of their absolute value is prime. I have to find the shortest number of dances needed to sort the array. For example, for the input `1 2 4 -3 5 6 7 8` the answer would be 1. Because 3 can dance with 2, (Because 3 is female and 2 is male) and their absolute value's sum is 5 which is a prime. So after 3 move to 2 for dance, the array becomes `1 2 -3 4 5 6 7 8` which is sorted. But something went wrong with my code. I have added comments so that it is easier to read. Here's my BFS code:

```
//Took input.
queue <array1> q;
q.push(init);
level[init] = 0;
visited[init] = true;
array1 v;
while(!q.empty()){
    array1 u = q.front();
    q.pop();
    /*
     We can view that the digits have an empty space on either side of them.
     Arr2 represents it as 0 when it is an empty space where a digit can come, or else the digits value (1 - 8)
    */
    int arr2[17] = {0};    

    //Loading the arr2 array.
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        arr2[2*i + 1] = u.arr[i];
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < 17; i+=2){
        for(int j = 0; j < 17; j+=2){
            //This condition checks if the digit arr2[i] can move to arr2[j] by satisfying all the condition stated above.
            if((j - 1 >= 0 && arr2[i] * arr2[j-1] < 0 && j != i-1 && j != i+1 && is_prime(abs(arr2[j-1])+abs(arr2[i])))
                 ||(j + 1 < 17 && arr2[i] * arr2[j+1] < 0 && j != i - 1 && j != i + 1 && is_prime(abs(arr2[j+1])+abs(arr2[i])))){
                //If it can, then swap the values.
                swap(arr2[j],arr2[i]);
                int l = 0;
                for(int k = 0; k < 17; k++){
                    if(arr2[k] == 0)    continue;
                    v.arr[l++] = arr2[k];
                }
                // v now holds the new state (or array / node )
                if(visited[v] == false){
                    visited[v] = true;
                    printf("visited[v]: %d\n",visited[v]); // the error is shown here. It prints visited[v] as 0. But I assigned it as true just before this line. Nothing else happened. Why it is 0?
                    v.print();
                    level[v] = level[u] + 1;
                    q.push(v);
                    if(v.is_sorted()){
                    while(!q.empty()) q.pop();
                        ans = level[v];
                        i = j = 100000; break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my array1 class:

```
class array1{
public:
int arr[8];

bool operator < (const array1 & in) const{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(arr[i] < in.arr[i])
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool is_sorted() const{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(i + 1 != abs(arr[i]))    return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void print(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
};
```

Here's a screenshot of what happened
[image]

The line `visited[v] = true` should make `visited[v]` equal to 1. But in the immediate next line, it is printed and the value is printed as 0.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time and examine the values of all variables, where exactly did the observed logic differed from your expected results?

Comment: I suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: The index i is always pointing to a digit and j is always pointing to an empty space. So, if a digit wants to go to empty space pointed by j, then it has to dance with either the digit at j-1 or the digit at j+1. The first condition j -1 >=0 checks whether j-1 gets out of scope and then if the multiplication value of arr[i] and arr[j-1] is less than zero then at least one of them is female and other is male, then as the digit arr[i] cannot go to position arr[i-1] or arr[i+1], so it needs to be checked, finally I am checking if the sum of arr[j-1] and arr[i] is a prime

Comment: The arr[j+1] is symmetric condition

Comment: Where is definition of visited? Is it map?

Comment: Yes map<array1,bool> visited; map<array1,int> level;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem. Apparently the overloaded operator < is not working properly. It is not comparing properly. I was considering the lexigoraphically least array the shortest. So when I am going from 0 to 7, if I found a value in arr[i] which is greater than in.arr[i], `arr[i] > in.arr[i]` then for sure, the function must return false. For this issue, the map was not able to retrieve the object as it was comparing imperfectly. Here's the overloaded operator after I made it right.

```
bool operator < (const array1 & in) const{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(arr[i] < (in.arr[i]))
            return true;
        if(arr[i] > in.arr[i])  return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```